# Can i devide my training data and train every part instead of inputting my whole data at once?

Tags: deep-learning, bigdata, training-data

I have a big dataset of images 8k.I want to train this data on my PC but there is a memory problem.So I've thought maybe i can devide my data to 4 parts each containng 2K images and train each part alone on the same model.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of **generators** to feed data to your model in *partitions*, without filling up your memory.

You should take a look at this [tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) where they explain the problem and teach you how to do so in `Keras` (if that's the framework you are using)